# iPod Touch Updates

Tags: ipod-touch, itunes

Since I've upgraded from an iPod classic to a Touch, I've had a number of times when I've synced with iTunes and tracks have not been correctly updated, that is, they have not been marked as played that day, even when they have been played (all the way through).

Further, I've downloaded some tracks from a course on iTunesU, but they do not show in the playlist on my iPod Touch (despite being in the playlist on iTunes).

I'm running iTunes 10.10.54 and 4.1 of the firmware.  Does anyone know if either of these are known issues, or has anyone experienced similar issues.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - it seems to reset the playcount of songs that I've either skipped or only listen to half of before syncing.

Comment: Check my answer below, but in a nutshell the playcount reset bug is fixed in iTunes 10.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been asking the same question in other forums about resetting play counts when syncing.

One of the strong theories is that it is an iTunes bug caused when you recreate your library in *iTunes 10* **from a previous iTunes 9 file** (which is what I did).  Unfortunately though there is no obvious solution yet.

I have tried to solve to problem by installing a fresh copy of iTunes 9 on a separate PC and importing my existing library via the `iTunes Music Library.xml` file.

Unfortunately the trick for recreating the library by using the XML does not seem backwards compatible. Even if I modify the *Application Version* at the beginning of XML file it is not recognised by iTunes 9 and is overwritten by a new, clean iTunes Music Library.xml file.

It seems like a bug I'll have to live with until Apple fix the problem - I have submitted a bug report via their iTunes website.

Here is the thread from the apple.com forums - http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2697318

*edit*

The latest version of iTunes (10.1.2) seems to have fixed the play count reset bug.

Answer (score 0):

These should really be seperate questions - one for the iTuensU, one for the track playdate.

As  for iTunesU issue, when you plug the iPod in there is a tab for iTunesU - you may need to check that the correct items are checked to sync.

Answer (score 0):

For iTunes U: Make sure it's getting synced, (as Samuel said). Also, if they're videos, look for a Video Playlists section under Videos. That might let you play them from that playlist.

The reason you may have to do this: Apple wants to allow you to watch music videos/iTunes U videos without the video. This makes more sense for music videos: You get the song, and they video. You can  play the song without draining the battery from the video.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to run the latest version of iOS unless you're a jailbreaker.

To check out iTunesU content, go into the iPod or Music app and select "More" on the bottom right-hand corner. iTunes U should be in that list.

(Why do people say right-hand, not just right? It's not like hands are any different than other things, direction wise. Oh well.)